# Matplotlib fill_between edge effect with `where` argument

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot the region between two curves with different colors whether one of the line is positive or negative. I got edge effect with non-continuous coloring of the region when the curve changes of sign. Setting `interpolate=True` does not really help.
The edge effect is related to the resolution (voluntarily coarse in the basic example below) - enhancing it is not really what I want. Any better solution to make smooth transitions? Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

plt.figure()
x=numpy.arange(0.,1.05,0.05)
y1=numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x)
y2=y1+0.2
y1positive=y1>0
y1negative=y1<=0
plt.plot(x,y1,'r',label='y1')
plt.plot(x,y2,'g',label='y2')
plt.plot(x,x*0,'--k')
plt.fill_between(x,y2,y1,where=y1positive,color='green',alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(x,y2,y1,where=y1negative,color='red',alpha=0.5,interpolate=True)
plt.legend()
```

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q9Ff.png

** EDIT ** based on pyHazard's answer which is properly addressing the problem above, but I still encounter difficulties:

Revised case (see code) - I need to fill the area between two summed curves if they have the same sign, and between one of them and zero otherwize. The filled area must be continuous when the `where=` condition changes. Including a tiny margin indeed helps, but does not totally resolve the problem (filled surface still interrupted). What is needed there is really a `fill_between` where `y1=0`, which is a condition with no width... I would then just need a kind of condition `where y1-eta<=0<=y1+eta` but I am foolishly blocked there now. Any idea to make the filled area totally continuous? Thanks!

```
plt.figure()
x=numpy.arange(0.,3.05,0.05)
y1=numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x)
y2=[2.]*len(y1)
y3=[-2.]*len(y1)

eta=1e-6
y1positive=y1+eta>=0
y1negative=y1-eta<=0

plt.plot(x,x*0,'--k')
plt.plot(x,y1,'.-k',label='y1')
plt.plot(x,y2,'.-g',label='y2')
plt.plot(x,y3,'.-r',label='y3')

plt.fill_between(x,y2+y1,y1,where=y1positive,color='green',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0)
plt.fill_between(x,y2,0,where=y1negative,color='green',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0)
plt.fill_between(x,y3+y1,y1,where=y1negative,color='red',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0) 
plt.fill_between(x,y3,0,where=y1positive,color='red',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0) 

plt.legend()
```

[image: fill_between_2]

To make it clearer, here is the original plot (with `eta=0.` in the code above). Everything is fine there, except those vertical interruptions in the green and red areas. The blank areas between the sine curve and zero are fine. The problematic vertical interruptions come from the definition of the filled areas: between the sine and the horizontal curve if they have the same sign, or between the horizontal curve and zero if the sine and the horizontal curve have opposite signs. So there is a switch in the conditions for filled areas, the blank vertical zones are the undesirable edge effects...

[image: fill_between_3]

*** FINAL EDIT *** [with solution]

Because I cannot find a solution within `fill_between`, one solution (based on pyHazard's answer) is to recalculate the upper and lower limit of the filled areas to make sure to have them continuous (no more swith in `fill_between` condition).

```
plt.figure()
x=numpy.arange(0.,3.05,0.05)
y1=numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x)
y2=[2.]*len(y1)
y3=[-2.]*len(y1)

y1positive=y1>=0
y1negative=y1<=0

plt.plot(x,x*0,'--k')
plt.plot(x,y1,'.-k',label='y1')
plt.plot(x,y2,'.-g',label='y2')
plt.plot(x,y3,'.-r',label='y3')

#Solution: recalculate the upper and lower limit of filled areas
#  to have each of them as one continuous line
y0=[0.]*len(y1)
y1pos=numpy.amax(numpy.vstack((y1,y0)),axis=0.)
y1neg=numpy.amin(numpy.vstack((y1,y0)),axis=0.)
y21=y2+y1pos
y31=y3+y1neg

plt.fill_between(x,y21,y1pos,color='green',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0)
plt.fill_between(x,y31,y1neg,color='red',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0) 

plt.legend()
```

[image: fill_between_4]

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are only concerned with one line or the other I suggest looking at your comparison. The following produces a more pleasing plot. (Note the plotting style was changed to make the data points clear.)

If you had intended all of the AREA on the negative side to be red and positive side green you will need to add additional data-points to the series that that lie on the axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

plt.figure()
x=numpy.arange(0.,1.05,0.05)
y1=numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x)
y2=y1+0.2

eta=1e-6
y1positive=(y1+eta)>=0
y1negative=(y1-eta)<=0

plt.plot(x,y1,'-r',label='y1')
plt.plot(x,y2,'-g',label='y2')
plt.plot(x,x*0,'--k')
plt.fill_between(x,y2,y1,where=y1positive,color='green',alpha=0.5,interpolate=False)
plt.fill_between(x,y2,y1,where=y1negative,color='red',alpha=0.5,interpolate=False)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

** EDIT ** I cannot yet comment so I'm adding this to an edit. I'm new to the forum scene so I'm not sure if this is considered proper etiquette.

I'm not sure I understand the revised situation. Are you simply trying to fill the white areas in with red and green? If so you probably don't need the extra conditionals and just need to to the fill between in the simplest way as shown below.

```
plt.figure()
x=numpy.arange(0.,3.05,0.05)
y1=numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*x)
y2=[ 2.]*len(y1)
y3=[-2.]*len(y1)

y21 = numpy.amax(numpy.vstack((y2,y2+y1)), axis=0)
y31 = numpy.amin(numpy.vstack((y3,y3+y1)), axis=0)

plt.plot(x,x*0,'--k')
plt.fill_between(x,y21,y1,color='green',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0)
plt.fill_between(x,y31,y1,color='red',alpha=0.5,linewidth=0) 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @pyHazard - it helps and indeed answer the question as formulated. Yet my problem is slightly different actually - hence I edited my question to make it more complete. BTW sorry I cannot vote...

Comment: Thanks again @pyHazard - sorry I was not clear, the problem was not the blank area between the sine curve and zero, but the vertical interruption in the filled areas (more visible when eta=0., as edited in my post). Yet you inspired one solution for me - thanks!

Comment: Looks like I have enough rep to comment now. Glad you found your solution. I'm guessing the moral to the story is: "Don't use stacked plots with where clause's unless you really need to avoid making a new series."

Comment: Yes - here making new series is ok, but I would be curious to learn about another solution (inside matplotlib?) if someone ever has inspiration... [and thanks again, @pyHazard]