# Matplotlib blank space with no color when use fill_between with where option

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Update:**

I slice days into 100 points then interpolate the corresponding value of `min_temp` and `max_temp`, the result become better, but still some area have no color, how to modify it?

```
days_vals=numpy.linspace(1,10,100)
min_interp=numpy.interp(days_vals,days,min_temp)
max_interp=numpy.interp(days_vals,days,max_temp)
plt.xticks(days)
plt.plot(days_vals,min_interp,c='b',marker='o')
plt.plot(days_vals,max_interp,c='g',marker='o')
plt.fill_between(days_vals,min_interp,max_interp,where=[i>35 for i in min_interp],
             facecolor='lightgreen',alpha=0.7,interpolate=False)
plt.fill_between(days_vals,min_interp,max_interp,where=[i<=35 for i in min_interp],
             facecolor='lightpink',alpha=0.7,interpolate=False)
```

[image]

==========================================================================

I am using fill_between with where option to fill the color, `min_temp > 35` fill green and `min_temp <= 35` fill pink, but see the result is not as my expected
there are so many blank area with no color.
[image]

I search one question somelike my issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214274/matplotlib-fill-between-edge-effect-with-where-argument)

it solution is to add additional data-points to the series that that lie on the axis, but it not fix my issue

**How can i modify my codes to make the color continuous with no blank space?**

here's the codes:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

days=range(1,11)
max_temp=[37, 35, 42, 36, 39, 56, 50, 45, 41, 39]
min_temp=[32, 30, 37, 20, 34, 40, 37, 38, 32, 30]
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
font={'weight':'normal',
      'color':'cyan',
      'fontsize':24,
      }
plt.title('Weather 2014',fontdict=font)
plt.xlabel('Month',fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Temperature',fontdict=font)
plt.title('Weather 2014',fontdict=font)
plt.xlabel('Month',fontdict=font)
plt.ylabel('Temperature',fontdict=font)
plt.xticks(days)
plt.plot(days,max_temp,marker='o',mfc='red',mec='None',markersize=3,label='Max Temp')
plt.plot(days,min_temp,marker='o',mfc='g',mec='None',markersize=3,label='Min Temp')


'''add additional data points'''
eta=1e-6
plt.fill_between(days,min_temp,max_temp,where=[i+eta>35 for i in min_temp],
                 facecolor='lightgreen',alpha=0.7)
plt.fill_between(days,min_temp,max_temp,where=[i-eta<=35 for i in min_temp],
                 facecolor='lightpink',alpha=0.7)
plt.legend(loc='upper left',bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: In the areas that are white the temperature is neither above 35 for *all* points, not below 35 for *all* points.

Comment: but the 3rd ponit `min_temp=37` really >35 and no color on this area, it there any way i can add more data ponit to make color continuous?

Comment: Yes, the third point is >35, but neither the second, nor the fourth. Hence there is no *area* (that could be filled), just a single point (which cannot be filled). To get more data, use e.g. `numpy.interp`.

Comment: I use `numpy.linspace`  to add day points and `numpy.interp` to interpolate the `min_temp` and `max_temp` base on the days, but still some area not fill color ,i update the question,how can i further modify it?